# Get proxy address on 'Auto Proxy Discovery' mode on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, networking, proxy

I am using Mac OS X (Sierra).
In my network preferences, the proxies settings are not configured manualy, but configured by turn on the 'Auto Proxy Discovery' checkbox.
[Screenshot of network preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o095A.png)

Is there a way to get the address (ip and port) of the current proxy I am working with?

Is it possible to get this information via a command line on the terminal?

(The command 'networksetup -getwebproxy ' not working in this case of Auto Proxy Discovery)

Comment: I have this problem too, have you found any solution?

Comment: The answer below is right

Answer (score 15):

Run `scutil --proxy` in Terminal. You will see the value of `ProxyAutoConfigURLString` in the output. Download and examine the content of the file at this URL and find those host:port strings prefixed with `PROXY`.

Comment: If you prefer clicking by mouse, I was also able find the PAC file URL in the System Settings => Network => <interface> => Details => Proxies

Answer (score 0):

I use the following command to list all the available auto configured proxy servers on mac osx.

```sh
curl -ksSL $(scutil --proxy | grep -m1 -Eioh "http.*") | grep -Eioh "\"PROXY.*:.*\""
```